# unexpected token break in ternary conditional

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, break

The function below is intended to return the values from a (potentially nested) object as an array - with the list parameter being any object. If I move my break statement to after the for loop, I don't get any errors, but of course then my function doesn't behave as needed. What's wrong with the way I'm using break?

```js
function listToArray(list) {
    var objectArray = [];
    function objectPeeler() {
        let peel = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(list);
        for(var i = 0; i < peel.length; i++) {
            list[peel[i]] && typeof list[peel[i]] != 'object' ? 
                objectArray.push(list[peel[i]]): 
                list[peel[i]] ? 
                    (list = list[peel[i]], objectPeeler()) :
                    break;
        }
    return objectArray;
    }
    objectPeeler();
}
```

Comment: [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) is a statement intended to be used on its own. It cannot be used as a value expression as the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) expects. To `break` conditionally, you'll want to use `if..else` instead of ternary operators.

Comment: Ugg.. from a readability point-of-view.. never, *ever* nest the `?` operator.

Comment: If you're going to nest the ternary operator, why not just use an if else block?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, didn't realize ternaries only took value expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue: ternary operators only work with value expressions, not statements (like break) and aren't meant to be used in these cases.

This works:

```js
function listToArray(list) {
    var objectArray = [];
    function objectPeeler() {
        let peel = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(list);
        for(var i = 0; i < peel.length; i++) {
            list[peel[i]] != null && typeof list[peel[i]] != 'object' ? 
                objectArray.push(list[peel[i]]): 
                list[peel[i]] ? 
                    (list = list[peel[i]], objectPeeler()): null;
        }
    }
    objectPeeler();
    return objectArray;
}
```

But using the jquery .next method allows a better solution:

```js
function listToArray(list) {
  var array = [];
  for (var obj = list; obj; obj = obj.next)
    array.push(obj.value);
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not writing something like this :

```
var obj = { 0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"}; //test target
var objectArray = [];
var keyArray = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++)  objectArray.push(obj[keyArray[i]]);
console.log(objectArray);  // test result
```